# Nature of the positional parameters

Tags: shell, function, variable

I wrote this shell script which sort of confused me a bit...

```
function func
{
the variables received are
echo $0: $1 and $2
}
echo in the main script
func ball boy
```

The name of script is shell.txt I expected the result to be

```
func : ball and boy
```

However I got

```
./shell.txt :ball and boy
```

I have read that the positional parameters are "local" in nature then how did this result come?

Comment: Positional parameters start at $1, not $0. $0 is the name of the script you're running. Also you should use `"$@"` in your script instead. This will give you a list of all the parameters from which you can parse the individual vars.

Comment: @slm, `$0` is not necessarily the name of the script when used inside a function declared that specific non portable way. The behavior is shell dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash some variables are reserved, such as $0 which gives the command name -- in this instance it is the name of the script (hence ./shell.txt). Another example is $$ which will give the process ID. I believe that $FUNCNAME should print the name of the function being used.

Any variables in the format $1 $2 $3 etc will be whatever positional parameters you have passed to it.

If you removed the $0 variable and replaced it with $FUNCNAME you would get the output you are looking for.

Here is a short script, let's save it as passingVariables.sh (we use .sh to show that it is a shell script -- purely superficial but it helps keep things straight):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The first word is $1 and the second word is $2"
```

Now if I ran it like this:

```
./passingVariables.sh apple orange
```

It would spit out the following:

```
"The first word is apple and the second word is orange"
```

Comment: Why don't apple and orange need to be quoted? I though any unquoted string is treated as a variable, keyword, etc

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is shell dependent.

You declared the function a non POSIX way. The portable syntax would have been

```
func()
{
...
```

You likely used `bash` to run your script. `bash` makes no difference between the non standard syntax you used and the standard one. In both cases, `$0` refer to the name of the script.

Should you have used the AT&T or public domain implementation of `ksh` which introduced the syntax you use and treat the functions declared with the `function` token differently, you would have observed the behavior you expected:

```
$ cat go
function func
{
    echo $0: $1 and $2
}
func1()
{
    echo $0: $1 and $2
}
func ball boy
func1 ball boy
$ bash go
go: ball and boy
go: ball and boy
$ ksh go
func: ball and boy
go: ball and boy
```